# How to remove all rows after a certain point by group using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
test_df <- data.frame(
  x = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)), 
  y = c(1, 2, NA, 2, 3, NA, 1, 2, 3, 1)
)
```

I would like to remove all rows **after** y == 2 by the grouping information in column x. Is there a way to do it in `dplyr`?

My desired result is 
From:

```
   x  y
1  a  1
2  a  2
3  a NA
4  a  2
5  a  3
6  b NA
7  b  1
8  b  2
9  b  3
10 b  1
```

To

```
   x  y
1  a  1
2  a  2
6  b NA
7  b  1
8  b  2
```

Comment: Does `filter(test_df, y <= 2)` do what you want?

Comment: @JakeFisher It won't remove the fourth row and it will take off all the NA rows.

Comment: I guess I'm confused because there are several rows where `y==2` (rows 2, 4, and 8).

Comment: @JakeFisher Sorry, Jake. I meant to remove all rows after  y==2 for the first time (including those where y != 2) (by each group)

Comment: why is row `4`  and `10` removed?

Comment: @mtoto Sorry everyone if I didn't make this question clear. Row 4 and 10 are removed because they came after/below Row 2 and Row 8 where y == 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
group_by(df, x) %>%
    mutate(first2 = min(which(y == 2 | row_number() == n()))) %>%
    filter(row_number() <= first2) %>%
    select(-first2)
# Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
# Groups: x [2]
# 
#        x     y
#   (fctr) (int)
# 1      a     1
# 2      a     2
# 3      b    NA
# 4      b     1
# 5      b     2
# 6      c     1
```

Using this data

```
df = structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), y = c(1L, 2L, 
NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: @Hao I modified your edit. This seemed like a weird place to use `ifelse`, I think `pmin` should do better. Also, you referenced a variable `b` which isn't in your sample data. I assume you meant `y`.

Comment: I just double checked the code. I understand the logics but somehow it still throw me an error `Error: incompatible types, expecting a integer vector`

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised. It seems to work outside of `dplyr`: `min(which(1 == 2))` just returns `Inf`. Anyway, updated again, and modified the sample data to have a test case for this.

Comment: Thank you again for your solution!! :D

Answer (score 10):

What about this way?

```
group_by(test_df, x) %>% slice(seq_len(min(which(y == 2))))
Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
Groups: x [2]

       x     y
  (fctr) (dbl)
1      a     1
2      a     2
3      b    NA
4      b     1
5      b     2
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is a very smart way of using slice and seq_len!!

Answer (score 2):

The solution from @DatamineR gives me an error because I have some groups where y never equals 2. I modified it by putting `n()` inside the `min()` call, and it now keeps all rows when y doesn't equal 2 in a group.

```
test_df <- data.frame(
x = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)), 
y = c(1, 2, NA, 2, 3, NA, 1, 3, 3, 1)
)

group_by(test_df, x) %>% slice(seq_len(min(which(y == 2), n())))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   x [2]
  x         y
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a      1.00
2 a      2.00
3 b     NA   
4 b      1.00
5 b      3.00
6 b      3.00
7 b      1.00
```